# Visual studio trying to convert a HTML page to ASP.NET

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio

First of all, I'm very new to this so sorry if this is a basic question.

I have created a website with a master page and currently 4 .aspx pages within the site and coded without the toolbox, a .master page with bootstrap for a navbar and some css.

The first time I have tried to drag a textbox from the standard toolbox I am greeted with a warning.

"Inserting an ASP.NET control will convert the HTML form in the page to an ASP.NET form and remove its current properties. Do you want to insert the ASP.NET control?"

From my understanding, I have been working within an ASP.NET form(using mainly html to design the page) as .aspx files are ASP.NET.

What are .aspx files? 
And will my website be affected by converting to an ASP.NET page?(The page I'm trying to create a page for users to log in.)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because I didn't have the code separated into a aspx and aspx.cs file